# What type does a function return when you just use return; in c++

Tags: c++, return

I use a function to return a obj I found in the data file. I wonder what type of data it returns when there is no corresponding obj. This is my codes.

```
BankAccount Find(string account_num , string password )
{
  FILE_IN.seekg(0 , ios::beg);
  int check = 0;
  string temp1;
  string temp2;
  string temp3;
  while(!FILE_IN.eof())
  {
    getline(FILE_IN , temp1);
    getline(FILE_IN , temp2);
    getline(FILE_IN , temp3);
    if(account_num.compare(temp1) == 0 && password.compare(temp2) == 0)
    check = 1;
  }
  if(check == 1)
  {
    fstream file;
    file.open(temp3 , ios::out);
    string name;
    string hist;
    string bal;
    getline(file , name);
    getline(file , bal);
    file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() , '\n');
    getline(file , hist , 'H');
    BankAccount account = BankAccount(atoi(account_num.c_str()) , atoi(bal.c_str()) , password , name );
    account.Enter_History(hist);
    return account;
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return nothing that way. You might be interested in [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), or possibly return a (smart) pointer instead.

Comment: Your program does not compile. The compiler should be telling you that the `return` statement must have a value/operand.

Comment: Please don't post images of your IDE unless you have a question about the IDE, and even then try not to. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed and should not compile without error. Using a `return` statement without operand/value in a function that has a non-void return type is not allowed, see the C++17 standard draft in [[stmt.return]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2).

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not work. You can only return a variable if the type `BankAccount` from this function.
Consider either using a separate function to check if everything is valid so you don’t have to deal with edge-cases like you do in your code or you return some kind of null-bankAccount (which I don’t recommend).

A `std::pair` could work for your. it’s not the best practice to do this but with a `std::pair<BankAccount, bool> retVal` you can use `retVal.second` to store a Boolean that indicates wether your program was properly executed.

I personally would use a try-catch block.
Like this:

```
  //Do stuff with Acc
  if(acc.good == false){
  throw std::invalid_argument("invalidAccount");
```

And then use a try-catch block where the function is called. That way you can *interrupt* a function. 
The best way is probably to re-design you Code so that this just doesn’t happen..

Comment: Throw an std::string ?? Anything which is not an std::exception should never be thrown

Comment: Given that the construction or copying of `std::string` can throw, it is not a good idea to throw `std::string` since (if `std::string` throws) that will either result in `std::terminate()` being called or an different exception than you intend being thrown.   If you care about the exception being (able to be) caught, use a type that cannot not throw on construction or copying.    `std::exception` and standard types derived from it are candidates for that

Comment: Oh sorry imma fix that real quick

Comment: @SchnJulian If i use Pair. It means I must create a new BankAccount Obj to return in case that the function didn't run well ?

Comment: @ThànhCông Or you pass a reference to a pair to the function

Answer (score 0):

IDE wasn't working accurately that time ! That code's ill-formed like @wallnut 's answer ! The function must have return type like the type in its declaring.